# sprintf segfault while printf is fine

Tags: c, windows, ubuntu, cstring

Is there any simple thing that I might have overlooked for when `printf("%s/%s\n", str1, str2);` prints out the string while `sprintf(str3, "%s/%s", str1, str2);` causes the program to crash?

This only happens on Ubuntu (latest release), which I am running on VirtualBox. On Windows (the host), both lines run without any problems.

If more context is needed, please tell me. I am hoping there is some silly thing I missed, and that those 2 lines are more than enough.

Comment: How is `str3` declared? How many characters can it hold? Specifically, can it hold `strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1 + 1` characters?

Comment: Have you allocated enough memory to it?

Comment: What's the `char *` pointing at?  The answer must be 'either null or random space' — either could cause the seg fault.

Comment: whoops. i managed to forget to use malloc. wow im blind

Comment: @calccrypto: happens to the best of us ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that `printf()` is writing to standard output and `sprintf()` is writing to the buffer `str3`. If `str3` is not large enough to contain the resulting string then it is undefined behaviour, and the likely cause of the crash.

`str3` must be correctly initialised (not `NULL` or uninitialised) and must be pointing to enough space to hold `strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 2` characters. The `+ 2` being the `/` and the terminating null character. For example:

```
char* str3 = malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 2);
if (str3)
{
    sprintf(str3, "%s/%s", str1, str2);
}
```